# Is it possible in VS Code to get choice suggestions for choice snippets after the snippet has been completed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-snippets

In VSC I have a user snippet that pastes

```
call colorecho "Red;Text"
```

and It is set up in the user snippit settings as such

```
"Color Echo": {
        "scope": "batch,bat",
        "prefix": "color echo",
        "body": "call colorecho \"${1|Red,Cyan,Green,Blue,Magenta,Yellow,White,Red Underline,Cyan Underline,Green Underline,Blue Underline,Magenta Underline,Yellow Underline,White Underline|};${2:Text}\"$0",
        "description": "Echo But With Color, Text Blocks Must be in \"Color;Text\" format"
    },
```

and when I type `color echo` and hit tab it puts the cursor at tabstop 1 with a nice drop down menu of all those options. Which works perfectly the first time I type it however if I ever have to go back in and adjust the color, id like the same context aware suggestions, for when the cursor is in between the first ( and the ;

AND not ruin the suggestions elsewhere

I dont know if this is a thing, but i feel like its something that probably exists

I have tried enabling the Quick Suggestion settings for strings in the Settings. That brings up suggestions when the cursor is in said spot, however that brings up a very large and not context aware history of everything ive ever typed lmao. I would like if possible for it to just bring up colors.

Comment: when you type the prefix and tab VSC goes into snippet mode until the snippet is finished, I then loses all context of which snippet and where the snippet was constructed. You could use **Hypersnips** that can match a regex before the cursor and then recreate the snippet on the fly.

Comment: @rioV8 its too bad theres nothing natively built in. I took a look at Hypersnips but the documentation is hard for me to understand, tried setting it up and its doing nothing. thanks for the suggestion tho, maybe ill be able to stumble my way to something usable haha.

Comment: that means that VSC has to keep track of every invocation of a snippet in every file and do that also for all undo/redo. Or it has to try and match the current surrounding text with all the snippets it has, some of them are multi line and what if you alter the multi/single line does it need to find a match, if you alter the options, .... For this snippet it is easy to write a regex to match the surrounding text. Maybe add a feature request to add a regex parameter so VSC can match the cursor context to the fields of the snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate it using the extension (I wrote) [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) and a keybinding that executes multiple commands.

If the cursor is at the place of the **color** in the previous snippet it will select the color and start a snippet that shows the list of possible colors.

If the cursor is at any other place the key binding just inserts a color at that location.

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f8",   // any key combo
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        {
          "command": "selectby.regex",
          "args": {
            "surround": "(?<=call colorecho \")[ a-zA-Z]+(?=;)"
          }
        },
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "${1|Red,Cyan,Green,Blue,Magenta,Yellow,White,Red Underline,Cyan Underline,Green Underline,Blue Underline,Magenta Underline,Yellow Underline,White Underline|}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

If you escape the snippet because you don't want to modify the color you have to do an **Undo** (`Ctrl+Z`).

If your version of VSC does not support `runCommands` (added in a version >1.75) you can use [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f8",   // any key combo
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
        {
          "command": "selectby.regex",
          "args": {
            "surround": "(?<=call colorecho \")[ a-zA-Z]+(?=;)"
          }
        },
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "${1|Red,Cyan,Green,Blue,Magenta,Yellow,White,Red Underline,Cyan Underline,Green Underline,Blue Underline,Magenta Underline,Yellow Underline,White Underline|}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```